# jQuery UI datepicker not behaving as expected on dynamically loaded fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am applying date picker on few dynamically loaded elements on my webpage. These elements are loaded through AJAX. Following is the code snippet.

```
$('body').on('click','#guaQuestions205\\.answer, #guaQuestions206\\.answer',function(){

            alert('Changing');
            $( "#guaQuestions205\\.answer" ).datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth:true,
                        changeYear:true ,
                        yearRange: '1900:2025',
                        maxDate: new Date(),
                        onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
                        {
                            alert('Changing');
                            $("#guaQuestions206\\.answer").val('');
                            $("#guaQuestions206\\.answer").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
                        }

                    });

            $( "#guaQuestions206\\.answer" ).datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                        changeMonth:true,
                        changeYear:true,
                        yearRange: '1900:2025'
                    }); 

        });
```

This code applies datepicker on those(elements loaded through AJAX). However the properties which are mentioned are not applied. For e.g. the `maxDate` is not set.Also the function

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
                        {
                            alert('Changing');
                            $("#guaQuestions206\\.answer").val('');
                            $("#guaQuestions206\\.answer").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
                        }
```

does not work.

What could be the reason ? Any solutions ?

Comment: Seems to work... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDUuu/) And minDate is set, not maxDate as you mentioned.

Comment: The Elements are loaded dynamically through AJAX. The fiddle you have shared have it all on page load itself.

Comment: Elements like '<body>' are loaded dynamically? When are they loaded? Is the JQuery code is executed after the elements are loaded?

Comment: call it in your ajax callback function. `$.get("new_div_contents.whatever", function(data) { 
  // do your thing with the data
  $("#yourdate").datepicker();
});`